# sql query returning different outputs for the same logic

Tags: sql, count, sum, having

```
SELECT
candidate_id 
FROM candidates
group by candidate_id
having(count(skill = "Python")>0
   and count(skill = "Tableau")>0
   and count(skill = "MySQL")>0)
SELECT
candidate_id 
FROM candidates
group by candidate_id
having(sum(skill = "Python")>0
   and sum(skill = "Tableau")>0
   and sum(skill = "MySQL")>0
)
```

This is the dataset

```
candidate_id    skill
100 Python
100 Tableau
100 MySQL
101 R
101 Tableau
101 Java
102 PowerBi
102 MySQL
103 Python
103 MySQL
104 Python
104 Tableau
105 MySQL
106 MySQL
107 Python
107 Tableau
107 MySQL
108 PowerBi
```

```
type here
```

```
108 R
109 Java
109 PowerBi
110 Tableau
110 MySQL
110 PowerBi
```

**Final Verdict**

I tried running both the queries separately but I get different output ,shouldnt I get the same output skill= "python" should give me a 0 or 1 which then if I sum or count should give me the same result

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking whether to use `count(skill = 'MySQL') >0` or `sum(skill = 'MySQL')`.

For your use case, the correct approach is to use `sum()`.

In MySQL (which I suppose you are running), a predicate evaluates as `1` when the condition is true, and `0` on false checks. The problem with `count()` is that it takes in acount any non-null value - meaning that *both* `0`s and `1`s will be counted. The query returns all candidates that have at least one non-null skull ; this is not what you want.

Instead use `sum()`, since this is the arithmetic operation that you want. A sum of `0` means that all predicates are false. `sum(skill = 'MySQL')` ensures that at least one row in the group satisfies the condition.

Side notes:

- although MySQL supports `"` for literal strings, it is a good practice to use single quotes (that's the SQL standard, which all other databases follow)
- the parentheses are superfluous in `having(...)`